# 007 spy question in python. what am i missing?

Tags: python, list, function

I am trying to solve a problem called spy game in which you need to return true if there is 0,0,7 in order but they don't need to be consecutive, and otherwise, it should return false.
For example:

```
 spy_game([1,2,4,0,0,7,5]) should return True
 spy_game([1,0,2,4,0,5,7]) should return True
 spy_game([1,7,2,0,4,5,0]) should return False
```

here is my code:

```
def spy_game(nums):
    for x in range(4):
        if nums[x]==0:
            for y in range(x+1,len(nums)):
                if nums[y]==0:
                    for z in range(y+1,len(nums)):
                        if nums[z]==7:
                            return True
```

What I am lacking is though the return is false if the given condition is false. I couldn't find an appropriate place to put a return false because otherwise, it affects the solution. My solution seems to be right for returning true. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to `return False` if the current function finishes without returning True. Currently your function contains single for loop, so your `return False` will go after the loop.

Comment: The problem is though if i were to write return false at the end like:
if nums[z]==7:
  return True
else:
 return False
it would only return False if there is two zeros and none 7's after and if i were to write return false after that it would effect the solution.

Comment: How is solution impacted if you return False after loop finishes?

Comment: No, not as `else` after an `if`. Simply as the last line after the entire loop!

Answer (score 1):

you can delete all numbers that you don't want and search '007', like:

```
myList = [1,2,4,0,0,7,5]
myList = [str(x) for x in l if x==0 or x==7 ] #just 0 or 7
strOfMyList = ''.join(myList)
print(strOfMyList.find('007')>=0) 
#find return -1 if doesn't find else the first occurrence
```

In a function it looks like:

```
def spy_game(nums):
   nums = [str(x) for x in nums if x==0 or x==7 ]
   strOfMyList = ''.join(nums)
   return strOfMyList.find('007')>=0
```